# How do I upgrade an existing EC2 instance from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 through CLI with custom Ubuntu 18.04 image?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, amazon-ec2

How do I upgrade an existing EC2 instance from Ubuntu 16 to 18 through CLI/ansible with our own Ubuntu 18.04 image?

Tried below steps and able to upgrade from 16 to 18.04 but it used ubuntu common image.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

But the requirement is to upgrade to 18.04 using custom AMI which is already created with specific requirements.

Comment: You do not. You create a new instance at the AWS console and attach your data disk to the new instance. That is the ONLY way to guarantee you can go back to a previous setup. All other methods can lead to data loss or the loss of the complete instance,

Comment: EC2 instances are generally expected to be treated as disposable machines rather than "pets" that are taken care of for extended periods of time. If there is already a custom AMI available, could you not start some new instances and migrate any data from the previous system(s) to the new one(s)?

Comment: The problem here is, the instances are provisioned through terraform and configured through ansible and around 1000 instances are in place now

Comment: I would skip 18.04 and go straight to 21.04 :) Only issue is we found is mysql 8. A couple of noticeable changes there. But if this is anything like GCE/Google cloud the instance has software checking for the validity of the instance  and won't boot if changed from the inside. You can update your personal files but I doubt it is possible to  completely go to another version inside the instance.

Comment: Is there any way we can provide our own custom image in below command?, it will download the packages from  apt repository
sudo do-release-upgrade

instead can we point this to custom images

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and had to upgrade an existing 16.04 ec2 instance to 18.04. Unfortunately, I only had ssh access to the server and not to the AWS console to allow for the 'proper' upgrade path as suggested by others. In any case it worked fine by running

`sudo do-release-upgrade`